# angular2-flash-messages prod build failing

Tags: build, production, flash-message, angular

I am using `angular2-flash-messages` in my angular(4) application.
and I have added in app.module.ts

```
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
imports: [
    FlashMessagesModule,
  ],
```

on dev build every thing working fine.Getting flash messages.
But the prod build getting fail (`ng build --prod`) and getting this error.

```
ERROR in D:/<>/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/angular2-flash-messages/module/flash-messages.component.ngfactory.ts (1,1): 
Property 'classes' does not exist on type 'FlashMessagesComponent'.
```

Comment: https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages/issues/16

Comment: I saw that url, but not getting what to add, and what is the solution

Answer (score 2):

To quickly solve the problem:

Change your module import to as follows:

"...Another imports..."

```
import {FlashMessagesModule} from 'angular2-flash-messages/module';
```

Notice the /module at the ending. Seems like the folder structure changed @ the latest commits.

Answer (score 1):

Find the FlashMessagesComponent under node-modules->angular2-flash-messages->module->flash-messages.component.ts.

Just add a property names as 'classes' in FlashMessagesComponent and build again.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZaxN.png)

Answer (score 0):

the latest version 1.0.8 working fine